# Is there a function (python) for dilating neg. and pos. values in matrix

Tags: python

i recently searched for a similiar function like dilate. I just came to the point that cv2.dilate() works only for positiv numbers in a matrix. Having also numbers which are smaller than <0 just leads to 0 values after dilation. Is there a method which takes pos. and neg. values in a matrix?

For example:

```
output before dilate:
Matrix_M[0,:,:].min() = -0.4797
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), 'uint8')
Matrix_M[0,:,:] = cv2.dilate(Matrix_M[0,:,:],kernel,iterations=1)

output after using cv2.dilate:
Matrix_M[0,:,:].min() = 0.0
```

Applying a `cv2.dilate` function with `kernel = np.ones((3, 3), 'uint8')` leads to `values >= 0.` 
In this example the `cv2.dilate` function eliminates the negativ values in the matrix. My question is if there is a function available which deals with **neg. and positive values?** So after aplying kind a `cv2.dilate` function also consists of minimum values like -0.4794?
Maybe anybody has a clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Short expl. added

Comment: your input code and desire output with little bit explantaion.

Comment: `uint8`? this will never take negative numbers...

Comment: Unit8 is just for the kernel. Unit does not influence the dilation here i guess

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose to dilate on absolute values and re-negate them afterwards.

Pseudocode:

```
data = Matrix_M[0,:,:]
is_negative = data < 0
dilated = cv2.dilate(np.abs(data), data,kernel,iterations=1)
dilated[is_negative] *= -1
```